# Deserializing Guava's Table with Jackson throws "JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found for type"

Tags: java, json, jackson, guava

I'm using `jackson-datatype-guava`. I'm trying to deserialize a Table from JSON, but I'm getting an exception.

My code is:

```
@Test
public void jsonTable() throws IOException {
    Table<String, String, String> table = HashBasedTable.create();
    table.put("row1", "col1", "cell11");
    table.put("row1", "col2", "cell12");
    table.put("row2", "col1", "cell21");
    table.put("row2", "col2", "cell22");

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
            .registerModule(new GuavaModule());

    String tableJson = mapper.writeValueAsString(table);
    System.out.println(tableJson);

    Table<String, String, String> deserializedTable = mapper.readValue(tableJson, HashBasedTable.class);
}
```

The exception thrown at the last line is:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class com.google.common.collect.HashBasedTable]: can not instantiate from JSON object (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)
 at [Source: {"row1":{"col2":"cell12","col1":"cell11"},"row2":{"col2":"cell22","col1":"cell21"}}; line: 1, column: 2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:255)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromObjectUsingNonDefault(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1130)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:298)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:133)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3807)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2797)
    at com.gk.dfm.repository.impl.JsonTableTest.jsonTable(JsonTableTest.java:31)
```

It makes sense, since HashBasedTable has no default constructor. We should construct it using `HashBasedTable.create()`. How can I tell it to Jackson though?

On [this page](http://www.leveluplunch.com/java/examples/convert-json-to-guava-multimap-with-jackson/) I found how to deserialize Guava's Multimap:

```
@Test
public void convert() throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException,
        JsonProcessingException, IOException {

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.registerModule(new GuavaModule());

    Multimap<String, NavItem> navs = objectMapper.readValue(
            objectMapper.treeAsTokens(objectMapper.readTree(jsonString)),
            objectMapper.getTypeFactory().constructMapLikeType(
                    Multimap.class, String.class, NavItem.class));

    logger.info(navs);

    assertThat(navs.keys(), hasItems("123455", "999999"));
}
```

How can I apply it to a Table? There is no such thing as constructTableLikeType.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, try using [jackson-datatypes-collections](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatypes-collections) instead of jackson-datatype-guava, because [it *has been moved under jackson-datatype-collections to simplify management, release process.*](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-guava)

The support for Guava's `Table` seems to be incomplete, because there's [an open issue for adding (de)serializer for it](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatypes-collections/issues/1). Since it's open source, you can do it yourself (please contribute back if you do so!) - you can use what other other people wrote, like [this pull request in old repository](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-guava/pull/73/files) (also [see test for `Table`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatypes-collections/blob/master/guava/src/test/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/guava/TableSerializationTest.java) which indicates serializing is supported, but no deserializing though).

Comment: Thank you. I think I'll just convert `Table<R,C,V>` to a `Map<R,Map<C,V>>` and then serialize/deserialize it. By the way, jackson-datatypes-collections documentation should mention on the status of support of every collection in the libraries (especially if it's half-done - it's very misleading).